# Objective C - How to store NSMutableArray inside of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a way to store an NSMutableArray inside of an NSMutableDictionary, and then remove it again. What's the best way to do this? (Or, is this possible)

Comment: Uh, how do you store ANY object inside an NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: You can store NSMutableArray inside of NSMutableDictionary without any restrictions.

Comment: This is a routine Objective-C code. Please do property research before asking questions here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *mdictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray *marray = [NSMutableArray array];

[mdictionary setObject:marray forKey:@"key"];
[mdictionary removeObjectForKey:@"key"];
```